# c# WCF service - How to get textbox input value

Tags: c#, wcf

I'v created a "Login" windows form app with WCF, 
How to send the input username and password to WCF and check if the username in SQL?

```
private void loginbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string username = textBox1.Text;
    string password = textBox2.Text;

    //check username and password are not empty
    if (username.Trim().Length != 0 && password.Trim().Length != 0)
    {
        checkPassword.CustomerServiceClient service= new checkPassword.CustomerServiceClient();
        var enterPassword = service.checkPassword(username, password);

        //check input value here with WCF?

    }
}
```

I'm getting `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` exception when I add `string getUsername = enterPassword[0].name;`. It looks like the WCF did not get the input value from textbox, in other words checkPassword(null, null).

```
public Customer[] checkPassword(string name, string password){
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
             "Data Source = 11111; Initial Catalog = 1111;" +
         "User ID = 1111; Password = 11111");
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select customerId, customerName, address, password, phone from Customer where customerName='"+name+"'", connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read()){
            Customer newCustomer = new Customer(reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(3));
            string correctPW = reader.GetString(3);
            if (correctPW == password)
            {
                customers.Add(newCustomer);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
        return customers.ToArray();
}
```

sorry, I am really confuse with this question, hope you can understand my question, thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. What have you achieved so far, and what are you missing. It looks like your code already does what you want: "service.checkPassword(username, password)".

Comment: I'm getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array." exception when I add "string getUsername = enterPassword[0].name;". It looks like the WCF did not get the input value from textbox, in other words checkPassword(null, null).

Comment: Put a break point at service.checkPassword(username, password) then find out whether these values are correct and if they are correct then they should get passed to WCF service and there is some issue with service. Now you have to debug WCF client and service.

Comment: `enterPassword[0].name` - is `enterPassword` an array or other collection of objects that have a `name` property?  Also, can you post the code for `checkPassword`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that the service call got executed as `checkPassword(null, null)` because you call `Trim` on `username` and `password` further up in the execution sequence. You would have received a `NullReferenceException` before the service call if both variables were null.

One red flag that I see is that you are testing the trimmed (whitespace truncated) versions of `username` and `password` when deciding to make the service call, but yet you go ahead and used the unadulterated versions when passing them as parameters to the service call. Could it be that the service is not behaving the way you think it should because there is whitespace in the parameters?

What you really need to do is verify the values of `username` and `password` just prior to calling to the service. Ask yourself, "Does my service respond correctly using the parameter values specified?" The problem may be with the service and not the caller. You are going to have to do some old fashioned debugging here. That is something we cannot do for you so take off those socks and shoes and get your feet wet!

As a side note, it appears that you are passing a password in plain text across the network. It is not terribly difficult (actually it could be quite easy) for a middle man to intercept this information. And along the same lines I can see that you are open to SQL injection attacks as well. Knowing that you are using parameterless inline SQL I could tell you my username is `x' or 'a'='a` and that would cause all rows from the `Customer` table to be returned. I do not know if that would necessarily cause a security breach in your cases, but I hope you at least can imagine the kinds of havoc this could cause. I only mention all of this because your WCF appears to be security related.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem.

It is because I use the input username to select data from sql, so when I input a not exist username, it will give a error.

Thanks all.